# "Unknown path" when viewing a newly generated angular page

Tags: developer, civix, angular

I'm trying to get started learning how to make Angular pages within a CiviCRM extension so I ran `civix help generate:angular-page` and read some help text about an example. Cool.

Then I ran `civix generate:angular-page EditCtrl about/me` to follow the example in the help text.

I browsed to `/civicrm/a/#/about/me` and expected to see some of the content shown in my newly generated `EditCtrl.html` file.

Instead I saw a page with an error message "Unknown path".

[image]

How can I view the angular page that civix generated?

Comment: Is your js stuff loaded? Did you check the module registration in function yourextension.php->yourextension_civicrm_angularModules(&$angularModule)? Insert some test outputs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you first need to generate a module, à la `civix generate:angular-module`. Have you already done that?